# Choosing simple a database for IBM Worklight

Tags: database, ibm-mobilefirst

Which one of this database is good for offline database: MySQL, oracle, Apache derby or SQLite for my client-side android device?

The data that will be used - it primes for logging utilities and their names, the same  way graphics and diagrams

Eclipse Juno + IBM Worklight + Android SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL, Oracle and Apache Derby are DBMS that you can't use for offline storage.

With Worklight you can use the IBM [JSONStore](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html) or SQLite(using straight Javascript, SQL and Cordova Storage API)